# Is running `sync` necessary after writing a disk image?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

Common way to write an image to disk looks like:

```
dd if=file.img of=/dev/device
```

After this command, is it necessary to run `sync`?

*sync(2)* explains it only flushes filesystem caches. Since `dd` command is not related to any filesystem, I think it is not necessary to run `sync`. However, block layer is complex and in doubt, most people prefers to run `sync`.

Does anyone has a proof that it is useful or useless?

Comment: I have no proof. There is nothing better, so `sync` will flush cache, so freeing (later) the IO bus, so drivers will find that it is a good moment to flush own cache. But as far I know (like you), there is no direct effect. But there are IOCTL to handle the new device.

Comment: The usefulness of `sync` and friends depends on your system, devices, their firmware, etc. `dd` is a perfectly ordinary command with respect to the page cache, as any other. If you need to be safe when in doubt, use `sync` or `dsync` [ioflags](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html) of `dd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Run `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/device` after `dd`.

I tried to follow the different paths in kernel. Here is what I understood:

- `ioctl(block_dev, BLKFLSBUF, 0)` call `blkdev_flushbuf()`. Considering its name, it should flush caches associated with device (or I think you can consider there is bug in device driver). I think it should also responsible to flush hardware caches if they exist. Notice [`e2fsprogs` use `BLKFLSBUF`](https://blogs.gnome.org/cneumair/2006/02/11/ioctl-fsync-how-to-flush-block-device-buffers/).
- `fdatasync()` (and `fsync()`) will call `blkdev_fsync()`. It looks like `blkdev_flushbuf()` but it only impact range of data written by current process (It use `filemap_write_and_wait_range()` while `BLKFLSBUF` use `filemap_write_and_wait`).
- Closing a block device calls `blkdev_close()` that do not flush buffers.
- `sync()` will call `sync_fs()`. It will flush filesystem caches and call `fsync()` on underlying block device.
- Command `sync /dev/device` will call `fsync()` on `/dev/device`. However, I think it is useless since `dd` didn't touch to any filesystem.

So my conclusions is that call to `sync` has no (direct) impact on block device. However, **passing `fdatasync` (or `fsync`) to `dd` is the only way to guarantee that data are correctly written on media**.

If have you run `dd` but you missed to pass `fdatasync`, running `sync /dev/device` is not sufficient. You have have to run `dd` with `fdatasync` on whole device. Alternatively, you can call `BLKFLSBUF` to flush whole device. Unfortunately, there is no standard command for that.

**EDIT**

You can issue a `BLKFLSBUF` with `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/device`.

Comment: This is great info!  Are you sure about `BLKFLSBUF`?  In 2007 Jens Axboe wrote ["BLKFLSBUF doesn't flush the disk cache either, it just flushes every dirty page in the block device address space."](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20070116003854.GE4067@kernel.dk/).  You might need SCSI sync cache & stop commands as in [`sg_sync`](https://github.com/hreinecke/sg3_utils/blob/v1.44/src/sg_sync.c#L94), [udisks power-off](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/udisks-2.9.1/src/udiskslinuxdrive.c#L1485), or [`eject`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/v2.36/sys-utils/eject.c#L572).

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, [Chris Siebenmann found that fsync(2) on a block device does cause a SCSI/ATA cache flush to be issued to the drive, if enabled](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/ForceDiskFlushes), which wouldn't be limited to the calling process.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't dig into `blkdev_flushbuf()`. Seen the name, I have considered it flushed all the buffers.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure the data is flushed on a usb device before to unplug, I use the following command :

```
    echo 1 > /sys/block/${device}/device/delete
```

This way, the data is flushed, and if the device is a hard drive, then the head is parked.